# Realm with Autoupdate, copyFromRealm, RxJava All together

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm, rx-java2

I'm using Realm's rxjava binding toFlowable to be notified when items are updated. I have to do this in the UI Thread to get update notification from realm. on the other hand I need to make the results unmanaged to pass them between threads and avoid inconsistency.

```
public Flowable<List<City>> getLiveCityList() {
    return mRealm.where(City.class)
            .findAll()
            .asFlowable()
            .map(mRealm::copyFromRealm)
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

For Example I'm using diffUtils to update recyclerview's items and that needs to get two different lists (different refrences). I must do copyFromRealm in the UI Thread too because RealmResults should only be used in the thread they are created.

```
DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffUtilCallback(mItems, newItems), true);
mItems = newItems;
diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(BaseRecyclerViewAdapter.this);
```

Should I move all of this off the UI Thread? How can I do that?

Comment: You could avoid using DiffUtil if you used `asChangesetObservable`. And yes, copying the whole result set on UI thread on each change can be slow. You could move this stuff to a background looper thread. Although it is much easier with LiveData than it is with Rx. I've actually done it before with LiveData, but it is tricky with Rx. The solution is `AndroidSchedulers.from(looper)`.

Comment: Actually, I also seem to have done it with Rx. You can see the code here: https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack/blob/6265538d41dc5cca5eb0ed2d9ecfe9f30e0e2fce/simple-stack-example-mvp-fragments/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/simplestackdemoexamplefragments/data/repository/TaskRepository.java#L65-L105

Comment: why are you using a different scheduler for writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a HandlerThread and wrap it with AndroidSchedulers to use it with Rx as a scheduler:

```
    SchedulerHolder looperScheduler = new SchedulerHolder(); // holds scheduler instance
    handlerThread = new HandlerThread("LOOPER_SCHEDULER");
    handlerThread.start();
    synchronized(handlerThread) {
        looperScheduler.setScheduler(AndroidSchedulers.from(handlerThread.getLooper()));
    }
```

Then you can now use this as `subscribeOn().unsubscribeOn()` for your RealmQuery running on the background thread:

```
private interface QuerySelector<E extends RealmModel> {
    RealmResults<E> createQuery(Realm realm);
}

private <T extends RealmModel> Observable<List<T>> createResults(QuerySelector<T> querySelector) {
    return Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<List<T>>) emitter -> {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); // can use custom config too
        final RealmResults<T> results = querySelector.createQuery(realm);
        final RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> realmChangeListener = element -> {
            if(element.isLoaded() && !emitter.isDisposed()) {
                List<R> list = new ArrayList<>(element.size());
                Collections.addAll(list, realm.copyFromRealm(element));
                if(!emitter.isDisposed()) {
                    emitter.onNext(list);
                }
            }
        };
        emitter.setDisposable(Disposables.fromAction(() -> {
            if(results.isValid()) {
                results.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
            }
            realm.close();
        }));
        results.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        if(results.isLoaded()) {
             emitter.onNext(realm.copyFromRealm(results));
        }    
      }) 
     .subscribeOn(looperScheduler.getScheduler())
     .unsubscribeOn(looperScheduler.getScheduler());
}
```

Then you can call it with

```
public Observable<List<City>> getCities() {
    return createResults((realm) -> realm.where(City.class).findAllAsync());
}
```

Don't forget to say `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` sometime down the chain.

Comment: why did you change findAll to findAllAsync?

Comment: Because the original code forgot to emit the initial results in case of sync query. So I kinda added both types (handle `isLoaded` and, well, both should work tbh)

Answer (score 1):

Modified answer of @EpicPandaForce https://stackoverflow.com/a/51916307/2425851
Usage:

```
public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
//...
mRealmStore.changeListenerObservable<City>{Realm.getInstance(builder.build())}
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe{list->/*do smth in UI*/}
}
```

RealmStore.kt

```
class RealmStore{

   inline fun <reified T : RealmObject> changeObservable(crossinline getRealm: () -> Realm): Observable<MutableList<T>> {
        return Observable.create<MutableList<T>> { emitter ->
            val realm = getRealm()

            val listener = RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> { realmResults ->
                val mutableList: MutableList<T> = realm.copyFromRealm(realmResults)
                emitter.onNext(mutableList)
            }

            val realmResults = realm
                .where(T::class.java)
                .findAllAsync()
            realmResults.addChangeListener(listener)

            emitter.setDisposable(Disposables.fromAction {
                realmResults.removeChangeListener(listener)
            })
        }
            .subscribeOn(RealmScheduler.background())
            .unsubscribeOn(RealmScheduler.background())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    }
}
```

RealmScheduler.java

```
public class RealmScheduler {
    private Scheduler scheduler;
    private static RealmScheduler instance;

    static RealmScheduler getInstance() {
        RealmScheduler localInstance = instance;
        if (localInstance == null) {
            synchronized (RealmScheduler.class) {
                localInstance = instance;
                if (localInstance == null) {
                    instance = localInstance = new RealmScheduler();
                }
            }
        }
        return localInstance;
    }

    private RealmScheduler() {
        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("REALM_SCHEDULER");
        handlerThread.start();
        scheduler = AndroidSchedulers.from(handlerThread.getLooper());
    }

    public static Scheduler background() {
        Scheduler scheduler = getInstance().getScheduler();
        if (scheduler == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("realm scheduler == null");
        }
        return scheduler;
    }

    private Scheduler getScheduler() {
        return scheduler;
    }

}
```